# Replace certain value in R Failed

Tags: r, replace, filter

I was trying to replace values >= 4 in column cnt1 with ">4"

```
   date         cnt1  cnt2  cnt3    cnt4
  2014-01        3    0     0         1
  2014-01        5    0     0         2
  2014-01        8    3     0         4
  2014-01       32   29     0        30
  2014-01        3    3     0         3   
  2014-01        1    1     0         1
  2014-01        1    1     0         1
```

My code goes like this:

```
output$cnt1[output$cnt1>= "4"] <- ">=4"
```

And the result is like below:

```
date             cnt1  cnt2  cnt3    cnt4
      2014-01        3    0     0         1
      2014-01       >4    0     0         2
      2014-01       >4    3     0         4
      2014-01       32   29     0        30
      2014-01        3    3     0         3   
      2014-01        1    1     0         1
      2014-01        1    1     0         1
```

So it turns out that some values were not replaced.... Did I do something wrong?
The Str of the data:

```
 $ cnt1: chr  "1" "1" "2" "2" ...
 $ cnt2: chr  "1" "1" "1" "0" ...
 $ cnt3: chr  "0" "0" "0" "0" ...
 $ cnt4: int  1 1 1 1 1 1 5 4 1 1 ...
```

Thanks

Comment: `"32"` as a string is not greater than `"4"` as a string. You need to compare like with like, i.e. - `output$cnt1 >= 4` - and ideally make a new column instead of trying to write characters into an existing numeric column,

Comment: I changed the code as `output$cnt1[as.numeric(output$cnt1)>= "4"] <- ">=4"` and looks it worked... Just wondering if string is not greater than another string... Why some of the values have been changed while some are not. Thanks. @thelatemail

Comment: Before that: output$cnt1[output$cnt1>= **"4"**] - don't put `""` in there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @thelatemail pointed out in comments you aren't comparing the same thing

Imagine that instead of comparing comething as being greater than 4, you compared something as being greater than "blah"

Is 5 > "blah" ?
(is an integer greater than a string)

You want to compare integers with integers.

```
output$cnt1[output$cnt1 >= 4]
```

Not

```
output$cnt1[output$cnt1>= "4"]
```

As well as that, when you replace the values with ">4" all the other values in that column will be converted from a numeric type to a character type. This may or may not be what you are wanting

## Edit:

When comparing strings you will get peculiar results. R does comparison this way whereby it looks at each character converts it to it's asci values, and then compares ascii value by ascii value

Consider:

```
> "a">"b"
[1] FALSE
> 
> "b"> "a"
[1] TRUE
> 
> "3">"4"
[1] FALSE
> 
> "5">"4"
[1] TRUE
> 
> "53">"4"
[1] TRUE
> 
> "35">"4"
[1] FALSE
> "alpha">"alphb"
[1] FALSE
```

If you translate each expressions into their corresponding ascii values; it all follows

Comment: Thanks @aeongrail, different numbers are actually different categories. The purpose is to combine "4" and "4+" categories into one... So character is actually fine.        But I do have another question that... when I use `output$cnt1[output$cnt1>= "4"]<- ">4"`, some of the value do change into ">4". As in your nice example, R recognized some 5 larger than "blah"... Do you know why is that? Thanks